# Setting a state but still getting error when trying to use after it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get pinned article

```
const getCurrentlyPinned = async() =>{
      setLoader(true)
      await firestore()
        .collection('admin_control')
        .doc('currently_Pinned')
        .get()
        .then(snapshot =>{
          const data = snapshot.data();
          setpinnedNewsID(data.pinnedNewsId)
        })
    }

useEffect(() => {
      getCurrentlyPinned().then(()=>{
         console.log(pinnedNewsID)
     })
    }, [])
```

therefore calling it from useEffect and console logging it in .then function, but I'm getting its value as undefined. I dont know why I'm getting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very common stuff, I guess there must be some similar question over stackoverflow but let me answer it for you. States are asynchronous so it takes a bit time of course to set it.
Just do the following stuff.

```
useEffect(() => {
      getCurrentlyPinned()
    }, [])
useEffect(() => {
      console.log(pinnedNewsID)
    }, [pinnedNewsID])
```

the state which you're setting in firebase function, just pass it in the dependency array of another useEffect so that you will console.log only when its value has been changed(or set)

Answer (score 0):

async functions take some time to return data.

useEffect trying to access the data before it's ready. bc it runs immediately after the component renders. that's why **pinnedNewsID** value is Undefined.

do this instead: *use 2 useEffect hooks.*

```
useEffect(() => { getCurrentlyPinned() }, [])
useEffect(() => { console.log(pinnedNewsID) }, [pinnedNewsID])
```